# Odoo: How to add a conditional attribute in calendar view?

Tags: xml, odoo

I'm a beginner developer in Odoo and currently I'm trying to enhance the calendar view with some fields. The problem I have is that I want to display some field only if they are not empty. In other views I have access to "attrs" which allows me to conditionally set the invisible parameter. But it doesn't seem to work in the calendar view.

```
<record id="view_calendar_event_calendar_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">view.calendar.event.calendar.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">calendar.event</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="calendar.view_calendar_event_calendar" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//calendar" position="inside">
            <field name="field_A">
            <field name="field_B" attrs="{'invisible':[('field_B', '=', '')]}"/>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

I also tested it by using `attrs ={'invisible': True}` .  field_B is displayed anyway.

So is there an other way to conditionally set attributes? Or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
attrs="{'invisible': [('field_b', '=', False)]}"
```

"False" is working if field is empty

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but I made the changes and it still doesn't work. The field is still displayed.

Comment: what type of field you want to hide?

Comment: a text field ( field.Char )

Comment: it must work. you can try inheriting view by other way like:
```
<field name="arch" type="xml">
                <data>
                    <field name="email" position="after">
                        <field name="telegram_notification_meeting"/>
                        <field name="telegram_reminder_meeting"/>
                    </field> 
                </data>
            </field>
```
and add attrs there

Comment: Ok, that also doesn't quite work. Maybe I should also mention that I try it implement the module in multiple versions (13, 14, 15). In v15 it works - your inheriting approach and also with xpath - but in v13 and v14 the attrs is still ignored regardless of inheriting approach. So, I guess it's an issue with the older odoo versions

Answer (score 0):

So, after spending a couple more hours on the problem I came up with a rather complicated solution, but it works, so I'm gonna share it here, in case someone has the same problem (code for v13).

```
odoo.define('calendar_videocall_url.CalendarPopover', function (require) {
"use strict";
var CalendarPopover = require('web.CalendarPopover')
var fieldRegistry = require('web.field_registry');
CalendarPopover.include({
    /** 
    * Overwrite
    * Generate fields to render into popover
    *
    * @private
    * @returns {Promise}
    */
    _processFields: function () {

        var self = this;
        var fieldsToGenerate = [];
        var fields = _.keys(this.displayFields);
        for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            var fieldName = fields[i];
            var displayFieldInfo = self.displayFields[fieldName] || { attrs: { invisible: 1 } };
            var fieldInfo = self.fields[fieldName];
            var field = {
                name: fieldName,
                string: displayFieldInfo.attrs.string || fieldInfo.string,
                value: self.event.record[fieldName],
                type: fieldInfo.type,
                invisible: displayFieldInfo.attrs.invisible
            };
            if (field.type === 'selection') {
                field.selection = fieldInfo.selection;
            }
            if (field.type === 'monetary') {
                var currencyField = field.currency_field || 'currency_id';
                if (!fields.includes(currencyField) && _.has(self.event.record, currencyField)) {
                    fields.push(currencyField);
                }
            }
            if (fieldInfo.relation) {
                field.relation = fieldInfo.relation;
            }
            if (displayFieldInfo.attrs.widget) {
                field.widget = displayFieldInfo.attrs.widget;
            } else if (_.contains(['many2many', 'one2many'], field.type)) {
                field.widget = 'many2many_tags';
            }
            if (_.contains(['many2many', 'one2many'], field.type)) {
                field.fields = [{
                    name: 'id',
                    type: 'integer',
                }, {
                    name: 'display_name',
                    type: 'char',
                }];
            }
            fieldsToGenerate.push(field);
        };

        /*add new fields via rpc and call rest of original function*/
        return self._rpc({
            model: 'calendar.event',
            method: 'read',
            args: [[this.event._id], ['field_a']],
        }).then(function (records) {
            if (records.length > 0) {
                self.event.record["field_a"] = records[0].field_a;

            }
            var field_a = {
                name: 'field_a',
                string: 'Field A',
                value: self.event.record['field_a'],
                type: 'text',
                invisible: self.event.record["field_a"] == false,
            };
            fieldsToGenerate.push(field_a);
            return self._processFieldsAfterRCP(self, fieldsToGenerate);

        });

    },

    _processFieldsAfterRCP: function (self, fieldsToGenerate) {

        this.$fieldsList = [];
        return this.model.makeRecord(this.modelName, fieldsToGenerate).then(function (recordID) {
            var defs = [];

            var record = self.model.get(recordID);
            _.each(fieldsToGenerate, function (field) {
                if (field.invisible) return;
                var FieldClass = fieldRegistry.getAny([field.widget, field.type]);
                var fieldWidget = new FieldClass(self, field.name, record, self.displayFields[field.name]);
                if (fieldWidget.attrs && !_.isObject(fieldWidget.attrs.modifiers)) {
                    fieldWidget.attrs.modifiers = fieldWidget.attrs.modifiers ? JSON.parse(fieldWidget.attrs.modifiers) : {};
                }
                self._registerWidget(recordID, field.name, fieldWidget);

                var $field = $('<li>', { class: 'list-group-item flex-shrink-0 d-flex flex-wrap' });
                var $fieldLabel = $('<strong>', { class: 'mr-2', text: _.str.sprintf('%s : ', field.string) });
                $fieldLabel.appendTo($field);
                var $fieldContainer = $('<div>', { class: 'flex-grow-1' });
                $fieldContainer.appendTo($field);

                self.$fieldsList.push($field);
                defs.push(fieldWidget.appendTo($fieldContainer));
            });
            var r = Promise.all(defs);
            return r;
        });
    },

})})
```

So I add an RPC call to `CalendarPopover.js` to add the fields I want to the `fieldsToGenerate`. In that process I can set the parameter for `invisible` to `self.event.record["field_a"] == false` to make it true if the field is empty.